cubic hypersurface containing two singularities contains the line
This is exercise 1.6.10 from Shafarevich`s book. I am trying to prove that if a cubic hypersurface contains two singularities then contains the line passing through them.
My ideia is to use the jacobian criteria together with the the Euler identity, but things gets messier and I am not able to finish. Does anyone have an idea?

Do you know Bezout theorem?

You are way overthinking this. Restrict the equation of the hypersurface to the line and count zeroes.
